# unable to parse string in getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I am using jquery in my application and I am using ruby on rails. Now I want to get the data typed in a search box immediately during typing.Everything is working fine but the problem is that it can not catch the special characters like `#@$&()%` etc. Its working fine for all other numericals and alphabets. I am using the getElementById technique to get data from textbox.

Please tell me any solution to get rid of this problem

My jquery code part is:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var box = document.getElementById("tags");
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = box.value;
    $.getScript('/employees/new?pt=' + box.value)
});
});
</script>
```

Actually I want to send this captured data from textbox to my rails controller.My controller name is employees and action is new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode the special character in the parameter value using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

> The `encodeURIComponent()` method encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

```
$.getScript('/employees/new?pt=' + encodeURIComponent(box.value));
```